# How can I use tilt sensor in iOS iPad to steer a car?

Tags: ios, unreal-4

I am an absolute beginner with Unreal Engine. I am working on a car racing project.

I need to navigate my car left and right using tilt

I read tilt sensor value then break vector to (X,Y,Z)

As show in the image, I need to read Y value. I call set steering input and pass this Y value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: What's not working about the way you have things set up now?

Comment: it give me strange behaviour it steering around itself , I think I should multiple in number or something like that

Comment: Unreal blueprints make me twitch. Its hard to explain, but the fact that this `SetSteeringInput` function is required, taking the object to steer as input feels backwards. It loses the linear relationship I expect from node based programming. And I have no idea what that white line represents at all or what relationship the `Tilt` object has to the `SetSteeringInput` function (is that function a member of `Tilt` not `VehicleMovement`? That seems *doubly* backwards).

Answer (score 0):

after struggle with this issue I finally found the answer and I am here to share with all of you hope this help

[image]